# How to break a long line text taken from a data frame in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, word-wrap

I am trying to break (wrap) the label text taken from a data frame, I am not sure how to do it.[See in the snapshot below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eh810.png)

```
 output$plotly_1 <- renderPlotly ({
    
         
  inherent + geom_jitter (data = dataframe, aes(x = column_1, y = column_2,
                                                label = column_3, color = column_4))+
      theme(legend.position = "bottom", legend.box = "horizontal") +
      scale_color_discrete(NULL) +
      guides(color = guide_legend(nrow = 1))
     
  })
```

Comment: I figured it out guys. I just changed the label to text and added wrap_str (column_3), it worked for me 

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the author already found a solution